# How to scale tree diagram for nodes not to overlap in latex tikZ

Tags: tikz-trees

I am trying to draw a tree diagram using latex tikZ, and the number of nodes increases to *2^p* for every *p* step. For example,

[image]

The codes for this diagram is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=80mm/#1}, align = center]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I repeatedly find that the final nodes are overlapped, and it is getting worse when *p* gets bigger. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you need correctly set `sibling distance`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: and if you like to have further help, please provide complete small document which produce your tree diagram.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid you are either deluded or lying: that cannot possibly be the 'codes [*sic*] for this diagram'.

Answer (score 3):

only as exercise and show principle ... with `forest` is simple:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={% style of tree
    l sep = 6mm,
    s sep = 4mm                                               
%
    draw, minimum height=3ex, minimum width=1em, inner sep=0pt,
    font = \bfseries
          }
[x,for tree={circle, fill=blue,text=white}
    [a,for tree={rectangle, fill=black,text=white}
        [b
            [c
                [d]
                [d,for tree={fill=white, text=black}]
            ]
            [c,for tree={fill=white, text=black} 
                [d,for tree={fill=black,text=white}]
                [d,for tree={fill=white, text=black}]
            ]
        ]
         [b
            [c,for tree={fill=black,text=white}
                [d]
                [d,for tree={fill=white, text=black}]
            ]
            [c,for tree={fill=white, text=black}
                [d,for tree={fill=black,text=white}]
                [d,for tree={fill=white, text=black}]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

*note:* for add fancy stuff in your tree you need first to provide code for tree.

**edit (1):**
meanwhile @cfr provide complete code with colored nodes. so now i add my, more (rude) elementary solution...

**edit (2):**
and alternative the first solution, maybe more intuitive ...

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{
bb/.style = {rectangle,
             minimum height=3ex, minimum width=1em,
             fill=black, text=white},
wb/.style = {% white box
             bb, fill=white, text=black}
            }
\begin{forest}
for tree={% style of tree
    l sep = 6mm,
    s sep = 4mm,
%
    draw,
    inner sep=0mm,
    font = \bfseries
          }
[x,for tree={circle, minimum size=3ex, fill=blue,text=white}
    [a,bb
        [b,bb
            [c,bb
                [d,bb]
                [d,wb]
            ]
            [c,wb
                [d,bb]
                [d,wb]
            ]
        ]
         [b,wb
            [c,bb
                [d,bb]
                [d,wb]
            ]
            [c,wb
                [d,bb]
                [d,wb]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

> *Note that I think I ought not answer do-it-for-mes - especially, perhaps, do-it-for-mes which falsely claim they are providing code for problematic output - but sometimes do what I think I ought not. When I do so, I do so for me. If my code happens to be useful, well that's lucky; if not, I don't really care. I will typically be unsympathetic to requests for explanations, refinements, changes and fine-tuning. If they tickle my fancy, I may respond, but don't count on it. If you wanted decent help, you'd have provided a decent starting point for giving it.*

Forest or a Ti*k*Z graph-drawing algorithm will lay the nodes out automatically. Otherwise, you have to ensure sufficient space. How to do this depends on the code you failed to provide. Anyway, I prefer Forest.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\forestset{
  declare count register=lefelau,
  lefelau'=0,
  twixis/.style={
    lefelau'=#1,
    delay={
      tempcounta'=0,
      do while={> RR< {tempcounta}{lefelau}}{
        tempcounta'+=1,
        where n children=0{
          append={[\foresteoption{level}]},
          if={> R_={tempcounta}{1}}{}{
            append={[\foresteoption{level}]},
          },
        }{},
        do dynamics,
      },
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      circle, fill=blue!50!cyan, draw, text=white, content=X, baseline,
      for descendants={content/.process={ Ow {level} {\setcounter{mycounter}{##1}\Alph{mycounter}}}},
      where n=1{fill=black, draw, text=white}{draw},
      for tree={font=\sffamily},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  twixis=3
  []
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  twixis=4
  []
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  twixis=5
  []
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest layout]

Comment: i spare my node coloring for time when OP will provide MWE, but this seem is not going to happen ... mine drawing and coloring of nodes is not so sophisticated. now i add it. i still learn forest and your solution is very educative for me (+1).

Comment: @Zarko So should I. As I say, I think I ought not answer. Still, since I have, I might as well correct the structure, I suppose. Your answer may be more useful than mine precisely because it doesn't automate things as much. But I was answering for me and not the OP, so it is the whizz-bangs for my solution :-).

Comment: it seems that exploit this answer to learn something (well, me on some lower level) , but it seems that OP don't care much about it :)

Comment: @Zarko Zero-effort questions are often unloved by their owners :(.